Work done on a pull up
I use force to accelarate my body upwards and then I decelerate down. Both movements use energy, but the displacement is zero. I would say that the work done which is the energy used to move my body was not zero and maybe when going downward it has an opposite sign but still it feels like I used more energy to go up than down. Is the work zero because of 0 displacement?

The net force (muscles + gravity) does zero work, but the force of the muscles of your leg does work.

long story short don't conflate the physics definition of "work" with the way we talk about doing work/exercise with our bodies.

Quite apart from the human body – in your description the "average work" done over the motion is zero, just as the average velocity of a baseball player hitting a home run is zero, since he ends up in the same place. The average of a quantity is often not meaningful.

@RC_23 so can i talk about the work at a certain time and not an average. ??what that would be? I mean if i want to see how much energy needs to exert to have a sepcific action. How do we measure that?

When you ask about the work done, you need to specify by which force.
If you ask yourself, did gravity do work over the all motion? The answer is no: it did negative work when you went up and positive work when you went down, due to the displacement of your center of mass, for a net sum of 0. That is because gravity is a conservative force (a potential energy is defined and depends only on the initial e final condition, which being the same make up a difference of zero).
Let's assume you, as you probably are assuming, to be living in an external gravitational uniform field. Then we may ask, did you do any work going up and down? Or, putting it differently, did the bar holding you up do any work? The answer is no, that is because the displacement of the point on which the force is applied, your hands, is none.
Then you may ask, where did the energy needed to fight gravity come from, when gravity makes a negative work on you while you pull up, subtracting energy from the system. Well, it comes from chemical potential energy inside your muscles, which gets converted in gravitational potential energy.
Sadly, this process doesn't reverse when you pull down, even though gravity does a positive work, pumping energy. All this energy gets converted into heat, due to the functioning of your body. This loss happens even when you pull up, in the conversion from chemical to gravitational potential energy, so that you spend more energy than it would be necessary if the dynamic was ideal.
I want to stress on the fact that the only force you apply is on the bar, and for slow enough movements it is always equal to the force of gravity, and it doesn't do any work.

"did the bar holding you up do any work? The answer is no, that is because the displacement of the point on which the force is applied, your hands, is none." -- in that case, does the bar do any work on the person's center of mass?

The force that the bar acts on you is applied to your hands, which do not move, so the work of that force is zero. In the case of gravity, the force is distributed on all your body, doing work on every part of your body as it moves. Mathematically, we can assume that the all force and mass is concentrated in the center of mass, that is because gravity is assumed to be a uniform field.

If you want to go about it that way, consider that the hands do move in the frame of the person that's performing the pull up :)

Well you are right, indeed energy isn't invariant under a frame of reference change. We need to think about each frame separately. In the frame of reference moving up with the person, this time gravity isn't doing any work (because your center of mass is still), and the bar moves down, which means you are doing work on the bar (the bar is doing negative work on you), but this energy gets canceled exactly by the work of the reaction force from the support of the bar, so that the bar doesn't gain nor lose energy (assuming negligible mass). [Work does indeed depend on the reference frame]

During a pull up, in one frame of reference we see chemical energy getting converted into gravitational + heat, in another frame of reference we see chemical energy being lost through work on the bar (+ heat).

correct, but the thing I was also trying to put across, and that's more pertinent to what the OP has asked, was that despite the balance (both in the bar's and the person's frame) of work done by the person and bar, there are forces here that did net positive work. I thought it was most important to clarify to the OP, that having returned to the same place you started at ($\Delta{y}=0$) does not imply you did no net work, even in a conservative field like a uniform gravitational one, since work is always of a specific force, so it's not the total energy transfer of the system.

The net work done by you would be zero if you were a conservative force, like the force of gravity or the restoring force of a spring, because you begin and end at the same location. But you are not a conservative force. You burn energy converting the chemical potential energy in your cells both accelerating up and down.
But the fact is even if you did not decelerate down but simply tried to maintain your upward position you would continue to burn calories in that upward position even though there is no subsequent displacement. That's because there is a difference between physics work and physiological work. Physiological work can involve a force with no displacement. Physics work doesn't.
Richard Feynman in his lectures on physics described it this way for the example of holding but not moving a weight:
The fact that we have to generate effort to hold up a weight is simply due to to the design of striated muscle. What happens is when a nerve impulse reaches a muscle fiber, the fiber gives a little twitch and then relaxes, so that when we hold something up , enormous volleys of nerve impulses are coming in to the muscle, large numbers of twitches are maintaining the weight, while other fibers relax. When we hold a heavy weight we get tired, begin to shake, ...because the muscle is tired and not reacting fast enough.
Hope this helps.

Why is the physics work zero?? Work is the summing up of differential terms $dW = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{dr}$. Both on the way up and down one can and does apply a force $\vec{F}$ in the $\vec{dr}$ direction.

@Amit I didn't say no work was done in the pull up. Only trying to point out the the work done by the person doesn't necessarily equal the physics work. I will update to clarify. Thanks.

@Amit, usually on the way down the force is in the opposite direction of motion (you continue to apply an upward force, even though your body is descending).

@BowlOfRed -- yes... I actually deleted my own answer here because I realized it was lacking in the explanation of the downward part. The simplest way to look at it is to say that during the downward part, you are modulating the upward force you apply to be a bit less than $mg$ so as to create a net force downwards, but it's gravity that's doing the positive work, not you. You will actually do some negative work but not necessarily to make your total work vanish, e.g. to take the extreme case, you just completely relax your muscles and fall freely, thus doing no work at all on the way down.
